# How to pause a queue in Activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jmx, java-ee-7

I need to pause a queue in Activemq 5.13.2 inside an application and according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/32165140/1458556 it's possible with version 5.12 but I don't know how to implement it. Any Java code samples would be great.

```
@Test
public void testPauseQueue() throws Exception {
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
    JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
    MBeanServerConnection conn = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();



    ObjectName queue = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Queue,Destination=testq");
    QueueViewMBean mbean = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(conn, queue,QueueViewMBean.class, true);
    System.out.println(mbean.isPaused());

}
```

Exception

```
    at za.co.fnb.cii.relandheir.batch.inputprocessor.service.MessengerServiceTest.testPauseQueue(MessengerServiceTest.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:69)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:48)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Queue,Destination=testq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the names have changed from

```
  ObjectName queue = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Queue,Destination=testq");
```

to

```
  ObjectName queue = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:brokerName=localhost,destinationName=testq,destinationType=Queue,type=Broker");
```

Then worked perfectly after the change.

I discovered the newer name format with the REST Management API http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html

http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the MBean that represents the Queue that you want to pause.  So using JConsole you would connect to the broker, find the MBean of the Queue in question and execute the 'pause' operation on that Queue, then when you are ready to once again have that Queue start sending message you'd execute the 'resume' operation.

Comment: I'm currently following this tutorial [link]https://dzone.com/articles/managing-activemq-jmx-apis and I found the Javadoc [link]http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/QueueViewMBean.html Should work.

Answer (score 0):

If using OpenEJB/TomEE, you can find the MBean ObjectName name using [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html):

[image: JMX JConsole]