# ActiveMQ initializer in OpenEJB/TomEE

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-tomee, openejb

I need to start a queue in OpenEJB in a "paused" state so no messages are processed by the consumer until some related data is available.  I can programmatically pause the queue as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36608115/935154), so if there was some initializer function that is called when a queue is created I could use that method.  The queue configuration [documentation](http://tomee.apache.org/queue-config.html) does not seem to support setting the paused state. Any ideas on how to configure the queue upon creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the thread you link you will see a queue is not paused but a broker can be.

In TomEE broker is created from a factory using a spi (in tomee classloader so tomee/lib by default) so you can write your own if that's an option starting programmatically when you are ready.

Now I suspect you don't want to start connectors with the container but it is not an issue to start the broker. Said otherwise you don't want to be connected to any other machine through JMS to not receive anything but if JMS is started and deployed it is ok.

In such a case you can just not configure any connector on the broker and add them when ready. You can find brokers doing:

```
new org.apache.openejb.resource.activemq.ActiveMQ5Factory().getBrokers()
```